# Sort collection with two columns first by one column and then by the second one in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I need to order a collection with two columns both in descending order but firts take into consideration the first order the first column and then the second one, one column is just a flag (0's and 1's) and the other contains a date, I want to sort the data in a way that is displayed like this

> 1 , 5/20/2014
>
> 1 , 5/15/2014
>
> 0 , 5/30/2014
>
> 0 , 5/25/2014
>
> 0 , 4/11/2014

This is what my code looks like, but doesn't work, I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

```
extendCollection: function(Collection) {
    _.extend(Collection.prototype, {

        comparator : function( model ) {
            var dateCreated = new Date(model.get('dateCreated')).getTime();
            return model.get('isFavorited') > dateCreated ? -1 : 1;
        }

    });
    return Collection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator):

> **comparator** `collection.comparator`
>   [...] A comparator can be defined as a *sortBy* (pass a function that takes a single argument), as a *sort* (pass a comparator function that expects two arguments), or as a string indicating the attribute to sort by.

Note that the comparator can take two arguments. If you use a two argument `comparator` then the logic is nice and simple:

```
comparator: function(a, b) {
    var a_fav, b_fav, a_date, b_date;

    a_fav = a.get('isFavorited');
    b_fav = b.get('isFavorited');
    if(a_fav > b_fav)
        return -1;
    if(a_fav < b_fav)
        return 1;

    a_date = new Date(a.get('dateCreated'));
    b_date = new Date(b.get('dateCreated'));
    if(a_date > b_date)
        return -1;
    if(a_date < b_date)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

No strange mapping hackery or nonsense needed, just simple clear comparison logic. You will almost always use an [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)-style two argument `comparator` when dealing with multiple sort keys, reverse string sorting, and other non-trivial sorting tasks.

Things would be simpler if you converted your `dateCreated` string attributes to real `Date` instances in your [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method and when setting new values.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit of a hack, but this should do the job:

```
return -model.get("isFavorited") * Math.pow(10, 20) - dateCreated
```

Thanks for the correction below.

Comment: I've tried that and returns thee data in ascending order, if I try [-model.get("isFavored"), dateCreated];] it return the isFavorited column in the right order, but the dateCreated in the ascending order, I need the date to be displayed in descending order too :(

Comment: try `[-model.get("isFavored"), -dateCreated];`

Comment: I tried it but got the same result as `[-model.get("isFavored"), dateCreated]`

Comment: Can you have a look at the values that `new Date(model.get('dateCreated')).getTime();` gives back? Maybe there is an issue there.

Comment: The values look like this: 1399403536000, 1399928580000, 1400015296000, 1400015397000, 1399403494000, 1399403504000, 1399403525000, ...

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, but maybe this works: `return -model.get("isFavored") * Math.pow(10, 20) + dateCreated`

Comment: I used your solution, but a little different and solved my problem: -`model.get("isFavorited") * Math.pow(10, 20) + -dateCreated` Thank you very much!!!! Could you answer with that solution to mark it a the solution.